# how to resize image width and height in excel using apache poi in java

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I used picture.resize that not worked

If the picture size is big that it become large i want that picture fit into the excel cell
if picture is big that it will resize according to the cell i want a rectange cell

here is the picture of excel sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB8oI.png)

here is the code that i write i inster data in two column and three rows
i made it static but data will come dynamically

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet2");

    Cell cell1 = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    Cell cell2 = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0);
    cell1.setCellValue("this is Image1");
    cell2.setCellValue("this is Image2");

    InputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Image1.png");
    InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Image2.png");

    byte[] inputImage1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream1);
    byte[] inputImage2 = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream2);

    int inputImagePicture1 = workbook.addPicture(inputImage1 , Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    int inputImagePicture2 = workbook.addPicture(inputImage2 , Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

    inputStream1.close();
    inputStream2.close();

    CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

    Drawing<?> drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    ClientAnchor forImage1 = helper.createClientAnchor();
    ClientAnchor forImage2 = helper.createClientAnchor();


    forImage1.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
    forImage2.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    forImage1.setCol1(1);
    forImage1.setCol2(2);
    forImage1.setRow1(0);
    forImage1.setRow2(1);

    forImage2.setCol1(1);
    forImage2.setCol2(2);
    forImage2.setRow1(1);
    forImage2.setRow2(2);

     drawing.createPicture(forImage1 , inputImagePicture1);
     drawing.createPicture(forImage2 , inputImagePicture2);


    int widthUnit = 25*256;
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1,widthUnit);

    short heightUnit = 60*20;
    cell1.getRow().setHeight(heightUnit);
    cell2.getRow().setHeight(heightUnit);


    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

    try(FileOutputStream saveExcel = new FileOutputStream("target/newWorkbook.xls")) {
          workbook.write(saveExcel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

anchor.setCol1(colStart); //Col Start
anchor.setRow1(rowStart); //Row Start
anchor.setCol2(colEnd); //Col End
anchor.setRow2(rowEnd); //Row End

//create a picture anchored to Top-Left Corner
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
pict.resize(1);
```